# PDF for a random variable with a step in density at one point (Dirac delta?)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution, dirac-delta, step-function

**Dirac background and problem statement:**

The Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ defined as
$$
\delta(x) = \lim_{c \to 0} \delta_c(x) \\
\delta_c(x) = \begin{cases}
1/c && |x| \leq \frac c2 \\
0 && |x| > \frac c2
\end{cases}
$$
can be used as the probability density function for a random variable $Y$ whose CDF is the unit step function:
$$
\begin{align}
&F_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
0 && y < 0 \\
1 &&  y \geq 0
\end{cases} \\
&f_Y(y) = \delta(y)
\end{align}
$$

I'm trying to define the PDF for another random variable with a step function CDF, $X$ (parameterized by a), which is the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ but with a size $a$ step in density at $x=\frac 12$.

$Y$ translated to the right by $\frac 12$ is a special case of $X$ with $a=1$, and the standard uniform distribution is another special case with $a=0$. Here is $X$'s CDF defined formally, along with an [interactive visual](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jkwvwjq3x7):
$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0 && x<0 \\
  x(1-a) && 0 \leq x < \frac 12 \\
  a + x(1-a) && \frac 12 \leq x < 1 \\
  1 && x \geq 1
\end{cases}
\qquad 0 \leq a \leq 1
$$

Can we use the Dirac delta similarly to how it's used in $f_Y(y)$ to help define $f_X(x)$?

**Issues:**

My first instinct was that we might define $f_X(x)$ as
$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  (1-a) + \delta(x-\frac 12) && 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
  0 && \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

But this is not quite right as the Dirac impulse itself contributes 1 to the overall probability mass in the CDF, yielding

$$
F_X(x\geq1) = \int_0^1 f_X(u)du = (1-a) + 1
$$

which is of course invalid for $a<1$ and doesn't match our desired CDF. I then thought the fix might be as simple as scaling the output of the delta function by $a$, as with:

$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  (1-a) + a\cdot\delta(x-\frac 12) && 0 \leq x \leq 1\\
  0 && \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

However, that also doesn't seem quite right to me because from my understanding $\delta(0) = \infty$, and I don't see how multiplying the point mass at x=1/2 of infinity by $a$ would actually reduce the jump in mass at that point in the integration of $f_X$ from 1 to $a$.

**Question:**

Is it possible to modify our definition of the $f_X(x)$ so that the Dirac impulse at $x=1/2$ contributes a mass of $a$ rather than a mass of 1, or to define a function analogous to the Dirac delta but but with a similarly reduced impulse mass? Or am I just off track with trying to use the Dirac delta for this PDF, and if so, what would be a better tool?

Comment: Think of the integral $$\int f(x)\delta (x-a) dx $$ as the inner product between the function $f(x)$, which could be though as infinited composed for infinities basis vectors (values of $f(x)$ in its domain), and just one unit basis vector $\delta (x)$, so $$\int f(x)\delta (x-a) dx = \langle f(x),\delta (x)\rangle$$. Given the above, it makes total sense that $$\int a\delta (x-c)dx = \langle a,\delta (x)\rangle = a$$ and not $\infty\cdot a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first instinct is quite correct.

$$f_X(x)=(1-a)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\left(0;0.5  \right)\cup(0.5;1)}(x)+a\delta(x-0.5)$$

now your impulse contributes exactly for a proportion $a$

Remember that this is NOT a pdf because your F is not absolutely continuous

Comment: Okay, now that I think about it some more, this makes sense. For some reason my not-so-good-at-calculus brain didn't want to initially accept that multiplying the delta by a would work, but it makes sense that if integral(\delta(x)dx) = 1 then integral(a\delta(x)dx) = a, so thank you for the sanity check.

Comment: And about the terminology: F would still be a valid CDF, correct? But f is not a valid pdf? What would you call it?

Comment: @ConnorRobetorye : Yes, F is a valid CDF. In some  branches like Signal theory these f(x) are named " mixed denisity. You cannot call it density because it is not obtained everywhere as a derivative of F. In your example $f(0.5)=F(0.5)-F(0.5^-)$